# How to properly index a large table?

Tags: mysql, index

We have large table(size:1gb)in Mysql 5.6 which contains 10Million rows..to be more specific it contains 360 columns, 60 foriegn keys..
My question what should be my approach while indexing this table?

**Extra Info**

### /*DDL Information*/

```
CREATE TABLE `t_ci` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text,
  `record_id` text,
  `last_modified_by_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_on` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_moved_on` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `archive` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_editable` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_change` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `blueprint_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `managed_by_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `department_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `license_key` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vendor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `confidence_level` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `credential_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `software_vendor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `memory_usage_weight` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `connection_weight` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpu_usage_weight` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_used` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `agent_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `packages` longtext,
  `services` longtext,
  `processes` longtext,
  `system_walk_oid` longtext,
  `system_walk_translated` longtext,
  `enterprise_walk_oid` longtext,
  `enterprise_walk_translated` longtext,
  `is_oid_translated` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tags` text,
  `second_level_support_user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `third_level_support_user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `second_level_support_group` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `third_level_support_group` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s1` text,
  `s2` text,
  `s3` text,
  `s4` text,
  `s5` text,
  `s6` text,
  `s7` text,
  `s8` text,
  `s9` text,
  `s10` text,
  `s11` text,
  `s12` text,
  `s13` text,
  `s14` text,
  `s15` text,
  `s16` text,
  `s17` text,
  `s18` text,
  `s19` text,
  `s20` text,
  `s21` text,
  `s22` text,
  `s23` text,
  `s24` text,
  `s25` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `s26` text,
  `s27` text,
  `s28` text,
  `s29` text,
  `s30` text,
  `s31` text,
  `s32` text,
  `s33` text,
  `s34` text,
  `s35` text,
  `s36` text,
  `s37` text,
  `s38` text,
  `s39` text,
  `s40` text,
  `s41` text,
  `s42` text,
  `s43` text,
  `s44` text,
  `s45` text,
  `s46` text,
  `s47` text,
  `s48` text,
  `s49` text,
  `s50` text,
  `s51` text,
  `s52` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `s53` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `s54` text,
  `s55` text,
  `s56` text,
  `s57` text,
  `s58` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `s59` text,
  `s60` text,
  `s61` text,
  `s62` text,
  `s63` text,
  `s64` text,
  `s65` text,
  `s66` text,
  `s67` text,
  `s68` text,
  `s69` text,
  `s70` text,
  `s71` text,
  `s72` text,
  `s73` text,
  `s74` text,
  `s75` text,
  `s76` text,
  `s77` text,
  `s78` text,
  `s79` text,
  `s80` text,
  `s81` text,
  `s82` text,
  `s83` text,
  `s84` text,
  `s85` text,
  `s86` text,
  `s87` text,
  `s88` text,
  `s89` text,
  `s90` text,
  `s91` text,
  `s92` text,
  `s93` text,
  `s94` text,
  `s95` text,
  `s96` text,
  `s97` text,
  `s98` text,
  `s99` text,
  `s100` text,
  `s101` text,
  `s102` text,
  `s103` text,
  `s104` text,
  `s105` text,
  `s106` text,
  `s107` text,
  `s108` text,
  `s109` text,
  `s110` text,
  `s111` text,
  `s112` text,
  `s113` text,
  `s114` text,
  `s115` text,
  `s116` text,
  `s117` text,
  `s118` text,
  `s119` text,
  `s120` text,
  `s121` text,
  `s122` text,
  `s123` text,
  `s124` text,
  `s125` text,
  `s126` text,
  `s127` text,
  `s128` text,
  `s129` text,
  `s130` text,
  `s131` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `s132` text,
  `s133` text,
  `s134` text,
  `s135` text,
  `s136` text,
  `s137` text,
  `s138` text,
  `s139` text,
  `s140` text,
  `s141` text,
  `s142` text,
  `s143` text,
  `s144` text,
  `s145` text,
  `s146` text,
  `s147` text,
  `s148` text,
  `s149` text,
  `s150` text,
  `s151` text,
  `s152` text,
  `s153` text,
  `s154` longtext,
  `s155` text,
  `s156` text,
  `s157` text,
  `s158` text,
  `s159` text,
  `s160` text,
  `s161` text,
  `s162` text,
  `s163` text,
  `s164` text,
  `s165` text,
  `s166` text,
  `s167` text,
  `s168` text,
  `s169` text,
  `s170` text,
  `s171` text,
  `s172` text,
  `s173` text,
  `s174` text,
  `s175` text,
  `s176` text,
  `s177` text,
  `s178` text,
  `s179` text,
  `s180` text,
  `s181` text,
  `s182` text,
  `s183` text,
  `s184` text,
  `s185` text,
  `s186` text,
  `s187` text,
  `s188` text,
  `s189` text,
  `s190` text,
  `s191` text,
  `s192` text,
  `s193` text,
  `s194` text,
  `s195` text,
  `s196` text,
  `s197` text,
  `s198` text,
  `s199` text,
  `s200` text,
  `s201` text,
  `s202` text,
  `s203` text,
  `s204` text,
  `s205` text,
  `s206` text,
  `s207` text,
  `s208` text,
  `s209` text,
  `s210` text,
  `s211` text,
  `s212` text,
  `s213` text,
  `s214` text,
  `s215` text,
  `s216` text,
  `s217` text,
  `s218` text,
  `s219` text,
  `s220` text,
  `s221` text,
  `s222` text,
  `s223` text,
  `s224` text,
  `s225` text,
  `s226` text,
  `s227` text,
  `s228` text,
  `s229` text,
  `s230` text,
  `s231` text,
  `s232` text,
  `s233` text,
  `s234` text,
  `s235` text,
  `s236` text,
  `s237` text,
  `s238` text,
  `s239` text,
  `s240` text,
  `s241` text,
  `s242` text,
  `s243` text,
  `s244` text,
  `s245` text,
  `s246` text,
  `s247` text,
  `s248` text,
  `s249` text,
  `s250` text,
  `s251` text,
  `s252` text,
  `s253` text,
  `s254` text,
  `s255` text,
  `s256` text,
  `s257` text,
  `s258` text,
  `s259` text,
  `s260` text,
  `s261` text,
  `s262` text,
  `s263` text,
  `s264` text,
  `s265` text,
  `s266` text,
  `s267` text,
  `s268` text,
  `s269` text,
  `s270` text,
  `s271` text,
  `s272` text,
  `s273` text,
  `s274` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s275` text,
  `s276` text,
  `s277` text,
  `s278` text,
  `s279` text,
  `s280` text,
  `s281` text,
  `s282` text,
  `s283` text,
  `s284` text,
  `s285` text,
  `s286` text,
  `s287` text,
  `s288` text,
  `s289` text,
  `s290` text,
  `s291` text,
  `s292` text,
  `s293` text,
  `s294` text,
  `s295` text,
  `s296` text,
  `s297` text,
  `s298` text,
  `s299` text,
  `s300` text,
  `s301` text,
  `s302` text,
  `s303` text,
  `s304` text,
  `s305` text,
  `s306` text,
  `s307` text,
  `s308` text,
  `s309` text,
  `s310` text,
  `s311` text,
  `s312` text,
  `s313` text,
  `s314` text,
  `s315` text,
  `s316` text,
  `s317` text,
  `s318` text,
  `s319` text,
  `s320` text,
  `s321` text,
  `s322` text,
  `s323` text,
  `s324` text,
  `s325` text,
  `s326` text,
  `s327` text,
  `s328` text,
  `s329` text,
  `s330` text,
  `s331` text,
  `s332` text,
  `s333` text,
  `s334` text,
  `s335` text,
  `s336` text,
  `s337` text,
  `s338` text,
  `s339` text,
  `s340` text,
  `s341` text,
  `s342` text,
  `s343` text,
  `s344` text,
  `s345` text,
  `s346` text,
  `s347` text,
  `s348` text,
  `s349` text,
  `s350` text,
  `l1` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l2` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l3` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l4` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l5` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i5` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i6` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i7` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i8` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i9` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i10` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i11` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i12` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i13` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i14` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i15` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b1` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b2` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b3` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b4` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b5` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b6` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b7` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b8` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b9` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b10` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b11` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b12` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b13` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b14` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b15` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_names` text,
  `unclassified_processes` longtext,
  `windows_updates` longtext,
  `vm_disks` longtext,
  `ipv4_addresses` longtext,
  `storage_disks` longtext,
  `machine_ip_address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hosted_on` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `iis_site_binding` longtext,
  `agent_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_created_from_unclassified_process` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_created_from_pattern` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_created_from_ip_connection` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_new_data` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `s351` text,
  `s352` text,
  `s353` text,
  `s354` text,
  `s355` text,
  `s356` text,
  `s357` text,
  `s358` text,
  `s359` text,
  `s360` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK362C114EDFB1A6` (`third_level_support_group`),
  KEY `FK362C1161C788C4` (`department_id`),
  KEY `FK362C11A3BC1456` (`second_level_support_user`),
  KEY `FK362C115EB8B9BC` (`owner_id`),
  KEY `FK362C11DD1C1817` (`confidence_level`),
  KEY `FK362C113F0F59C9` (`last_modified_by_user_id`),
  KEY `FK362C11C70A6B73` (`created_by_user_id`),
  KEY `FK362C11845A5083` (`third_level_support_user`),
  KEY `FK362C117F0A9464` (`location_id`),
  KEY `FK362C11762CEFF1` (`license_key`),
  KEY `FK362C11874EFF37` (`blueprint_id`),
  KEY `FK362C11A6A1BBF9` (`software_vendor`),
  KEY `FK362C114250AFDA` (`vendor`),
  KEY `FK362C118F53125C` (`managed_by_user_id`),
  KEY `FK362C111BB66833` (`second_level_support_group`),
  KEY `FK362C1174ABAEA4` (`credential_id`),
  KEY `record_id_index` (`record_id`(64)) USING BTREE,
  KEY `FK362C1171EA2767` (`hosted_on`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK362C111BB66833` FOREIGN KEY (`second_level_support_group`) REFERENCES `t_user_groups` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK362C113F0F59C9` FOREIGN KEY (`last_modified_by_user_id`) REFERENCES `t_core_users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK362C114250AFDA` FOREIGN KEY (`vendor`) REFERENCES `t_vendors` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK362C114EDFB1A6` FOREIGN KEY (`third_level_support_group`) REFERENCES `t_user_groups` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK362C115EB8B9BC` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `t_core_users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK362C1161C788C4` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `t_user_departments` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK362C1171EA2767` FOREIGN KEY (`hosted_on`) REFERENCES `t_ci` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK362C1174ABAEA4` FOREIGN KEY (`credential_id`) REFERENCES `t_discover_agent_credential` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK362C11762CEFF1` FOREIGN KEY (`license_key`) REFERENCES `t_ci` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK362C117F0A9464` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `t_locations` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK362C11845A5083` FOREIGN KEY (`third_level_support_user`) REFERENCES `t_core_users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK362C11874EFF37` FOREIGN KEY (`blueprint_id`) REFERENCES `t_core_blueprints` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK362C118F53125C` FOREIGN KEY (`managed_by_user_id`) REFERENCES `t_core_users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK362C11A3BC1456` FOREIGN KEY (`second_level_support_user`) REFERENCES `t_core_users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK362C11A6A1BBF9` FOREIGN KEY (`software_vendor`) REFERENCES `t_software_vendor` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK362C11C70A6B73` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by_user_id`) REFERENCES `t_core_users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK362C11DD1C1817` FOREIGN KEY (`confidence_level`) REFERENCES `t_cmdb_confidence_level` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=727863 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Looking at growth in future I have to **partition** this.How can I do that?

Comment: Choose the index based on your query, based on the info, if you create a bad index, other dml operations too hit badly. Also you may think of database partitioning, similar case I found better performance when combining with indexing on smaller data set..refer this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-overview.html and example http://www.rathishkumar.in/2016/09/mysql-partitioning-example.html

Comment: foriegn keys are not supported for partition in MySQL5.6. Is there any way around so that i can divide this table.@rathishDBA

Comment: You might be needing to vertically partition before horizontally partitioning. But it's a little hard to guess when so many of the columns have cryptic names. https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/mysql/w/wiki/6128.introduction-to-vertical-partitioning

Answer (score 1):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and some of the `SELECTs`.

- Do not splay arrays across columns.  (Or is there some other reason for so many columns?)
- Explain why there are 60 FKs.

The way to approach indexing is to take each `SELECT` and decide what the optimal index is for that select.  Be sure to consider "composite" indexes.  Be sure to avoid redundancies, such as:

```
INDEX(a) is not needed if you have INDEX(a,b)
INDEX(id) is not needed if you have PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

If you get to more than, say, 10 indexes, then you should make some decisions.

You should have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  It could be either a 'natural' key, possible composite, or it could be a surrogate (usually called `id`).

Normalize, but don't over-normalize.  In particular, do not turn "continuous" values (DATETIME, FLOAT, etc) into dimensions.

See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Partitioning rarely provides a performance benefit.  I have found only 4 use cases.  Please describe the table further so I can see if yours fit any of them.

Comment: is there any way I can get  a better performance looking at this size of the table @rick-james

Comment: Tiny tables work well even without the appropriate indexes.  Huge tables need special care in various ways -- to minimize I/O.  350 `TEXT` columns?  Ouch; that has its own set of problems.  Really need to see a `SELECT` to discuss indexing and partitioning.